# Play Framework return same values from different lists attributes

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have two list of relations in the class User:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="foreign_stories")
List<Story> foreignStories;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="preferred_stories")
List<Story> preferredStories;
```

when i try to retrieve data from those lists i got same data in both even i saved only in one.

i tried a solution find here that is

```
return Ebean.find(User.class)
                .fetch("foreign_stories")
                .fetch("preferred_stories")
                .where()
                .eq("id",userid)
                .join("foreign_stories","preferred_stories")
                .findUnique();
```

but I got an exception..

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting BeanDescriptor for path preferred_stories from models.User

Answer (score 0):

I find a Solution that works for me without fetching other tables and without get exceptions..

instead using the list itself declare an entity that hold the list.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
ForeignStories foreignStories = new ForeignStories();
```

where ForeignStories is..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foreign_stories")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ForeignStories extends Model {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Story> foreignStories = new ArrayList<Story>();
}
```